# How do I read unicode and a number arguments from the command line in C for windows?

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LPCTSTR f = argv[1];
    DWORD n = atoi(argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to read a unicode string and a number. This is what I get after I compile:

> error C2664: 'atoi' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '_TCHAR *' to 'const char *'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `atoi` you need use `_ttoi`. This is because `atoi` accepts only ASCII strings where as you are trying to pass a UTF-16 string to it. BTW, do not include `conio.h` it is not a standard header file.

Comment: hehehe and `<windows.h>` is very standard, I guess :P I mean ... not being standard is no reason to avoid including it